# Using picasso to get image from url

Tags: android, image, url, picasso

I want lo load the image from url and save it in a file in sd card and then load from file and show on image view.

So I am trying to load image using picasso. But its not showing on image view.

Here is url:

http://xesoftwares.co.in/contactsapi/profile_images/d34b638b93773140eb94d5f03c20237c.jpg

Loading image using picasso.

```
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(url).into(profileImage);
```

How to download the image from url. Save it in  file in sd card and then load the image from file to show on image view?

Please help. Thank you..

Comment: Do you really want to save into SD card? Picasso will download whenever you want to display the image and store it in application cache

Comment: ok but why its not working?@Stallion

Comment: Put up your related full code than a single line with manifest permission also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use GLIDE library it automatically store your image into Cache .....

```
   Glide.with(context).load(url).into(profileImage);
```

**Note:- Only first time you require internet for loading image. When Image load its working on without internet.**

EDIT:- use this gradle

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

Output:-

[image: o]

Comment: path to compile library? @sushildlh

Comment: picasso is working fine ... may be some OutMerroyExcepton in your device check your LagCat Error..... In question i updated output ....

Comment: I don't get any exception. @sushildlh

Comment: check you Logcat care fully ...... try this `Picasso.with(this).load(url).resize(1000, 1000).into(profileImage);`

Comment: can we get the file path stored by picasso? I want to store the file name in database. @sushildlh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124192/discussion-between-sid-and-sushildlh).

Answer (score 1):

Add :

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

In your manifest file, otherwise the source cannot be downloaded.

If you want to save it in sd card you need another permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

In order to save it.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If you want to get that file in the future.

Next if you want to save it to an external directory, you can try this:

```
    public void setUpDirectory(String folderName,String source){

        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+folderName);

        if(!directory.exists() && !directory.isDirectory()) {
            directory.mkdirs();
        }

        URL imageurl = new URL(source); 
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageurl.openConnection().getInputStream());
        saveFile(directory,bitmap);
    }


private void saveFile(File fileName,Bitmap bmp){


FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
try {
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream ); // 100 will be  ignored
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
finally {
    try {
        if outputStream != null) {
            outputStream .close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

To save it into sd card you must declare uses permissions write read from sd card in manifest, also ask user for these permissions for android 5.0+. All this is documented clearly in android developers official website.
 Change MainActivity.class to getApplicationContext()

Comment: I have declared the permissions. Problem is its not getting load.@rei koleci

Comment: Did u make the change I suggested?

Comment: Picasso saves in cache too. U dont need glide.

Answer (score 0):

If you have put an image as background of ImageView in xml remove it.